# Where does the standard talk about aliasing?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, language-lawyer

Where in the C++ standard does it talk about aliasing? I looked at the ToC and saw no mention of the word 'alias'. I tried to look in the one definition rule (3.2) and a search of 'alias' had no results there. I'm at a loss where it may be. I'm looking for memory aliasing

Comment: Could you please be more specific? There are at least two things that could be referred to by "aliasing" - namespace aliasing and data aliasing in the memory through structs/unions/overlapping arrays.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Fixed. Data/memory aliasing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aliasing is mainly discussed in §3.10[basic.lval]/10:

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
>   following types the behavior is undefined:<sup>52</sup>
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>     of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-
>     static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>     or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a `char` or `unsigned char` type.
>
> <sup>52)</sup> The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.

So, for example,

```
int x = 1;
*(char*)(&x);     // (implementation-)defined
*(unsigned*)(&x); // (implementation-)defined
*(float*)(&x);    // undefined
```

---

The following mentions may also be interesting.

§5.17[expr.ass]/8

> If the value being stored in an object is accessed from another object that overlaps in any way the storage of
>   the first object, then the overlap shall be exact and the two objects shall have the same type, otherwise the
>    behavior is undefined. [ *Note*: This restriction applies to the relationship between the left and right sides of
>     the assignment operation; it is not a statement about how the target of the assignment may be aliased in
>    general. See 3.10. — *end note* ]

§17.6.4.9[res.on.arguments]/1 pt 3:

> If a function argument binds to an rvalue reference parameter, the implementation may assume that
>   this parameter is a unique reference to this argument. … [The
>   implementation is free to optimize away aliasing checks which might be needed if the argument was
>   an lvalue.]

§26.6.2[valarray.syn]/2:

> The `valarray` array classes are defined to be free of certain forms of aliasing, thus allowing operations on
>    these classes to be optimized.

and the rest of `<valarray>` also discusses how the class should be implemented to avoid data aliasing.