# Accessing private data with reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This seems to compile and access the private data successfully. Is this well-defined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;

class foo {
    string private_data = "Hello World";
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    auto* pprivate_data = reinterpret_cast<string*>(&f);
    std::cout << *pprivate_data << '\n';
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11494403/10147399) question is sort of similar, but I believe it doesn't address my question.

Comment: It should be as long as foo is POD.

Comment: How could it possibly not work 100% of the time? Why would you ever use the `class`-keyword anyways?

Comment: @super of course it works fine in practise. I was wondering if it is technically well defined as you can tell by the language-lawyer tag

Comment: When would this ever happen?

Comment: If `foo` contains more than one member, I'm almost sure that there will be a strict aliasing rule violation for `reinterpret_cast`ing a complete `foo` instance into one of its member type.

Comment: I suppose the downvoter misses the point that language lawyer questions are not necessarily about code that one would actually write, because I don't see anything wrong with the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the behavior is undefined. For such a `reintepret_cast` to have meaning, the two objects must be interconvertible

> **[basic.compound]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.compound#4) Two objects a and b are pointer-interconvertible if:
>
> - they are the same object, or
> - one is a union object and the other is a non-static data member of that object ([class.union]), or
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object, or, if the object has no
>   non-static data members, any base class subobject of that object
>   ([class.mem]), or
> - there exists an object c such that a and c are pointer-interconvertible, and c and b are pointer-interconvertible.
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same
> address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer
> to the other via a `reinterpret_­cast`. [ Note: An array object and its
> first element are not pointer-interconvertible, even though they have
> the same address. — end note ]

The only bullet that *might* apply is the one about standard layout classes. If we consult that definition, we see

> **[class.prop]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.prop#3) A class S is a standard-layout class if it:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - [...]

there is an immediate problem. Any non-static data members of the object must be standard layout themselves. There is no guarantee `std::string` is a standard layout type. So the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Gotta love undefined behaviour!

Comment: What if it was `class foo { chat const* private_data = "Hello World"; };` and we tried to access that through `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @Ayxan - Then if we consult the list in **[class.prop]**, `foo` is standard layout. So the conversion becomes well-defined.

Comment: What about strict aliasing rule violation? Isn't [basic.lval/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11) enough to state UB?

Comment: @Evg - That is irrelevant. You can always modify `private_data` via a pointer that is obtained legally. It doesn't matter that its a sub-object of `f`. The question here is if the way the pointer is obtained is legal.

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong but I think @Evg wanted to say that _"the way the pointer is obtained"_ may break the strict aliasing rule (since we try to `reinterpret_cast` a `foo*` into a `std::string*`) and thus making it illegal.

Comment: @Fareanor - The strict aliasing rule doesn't care about how the pointer is obtained. And the reintpert_cast itself is not UB on its own. Using the pointer for *access* is what **may** trip strict aliasing. Or are you saying a class cannot give out pointers to its members to other function to modify?

Comment: It looks like we're trying to access `foo` via `std::string*` when we do `*pprivate_data`.

Comment: @Evg - No, we are accessing `f.private_data`.

Comment: You're right, strict aliasing may trigger only when we try to access it. But what would be the meaning of getting such a pointer if it's not to use it at some point ? And i'm not saying a class cannot provide pointers to its data member, but this is not the case here, we are trying to convert the class instance pointer to one of its members pointer.

Comment: @Fareanor - Yes, we are trying to convert here. And the standard says we can get the correct address, same as if `&f.private_data`  was used to obtain the address.

Comment: Ok there is something I didn't understand then. For me @Evg is right. This is `&f` not `&f.private_data` that was given to `reinterpret_cast` parameter.

Comment: Oh alright, I didn't know that. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Of course you could `static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<std::string>)` to restrict yourself to implementations where this is defined behaviour

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is fine on condition `std::string` (and thus `class foo`) is standard-layout (it [is](https://godbolt.org/z/87Mh3P) in libstdc++, libc++ and MSVC STL). Per [class.mem/26](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#26) :

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member [...] [Note: The object and its first subobject are pointer-interconvertible ([basic.compound], [expr.static.cast]). — end note]

And [basic.compund/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#4):

> Two objects a and b are *pointer-interconvertible* if: [...]
>
> - one is a standard-layout class object and the other is the first non-static data member of that object [...]
>
> If two objects are pointer-interconvertible, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_­cast.

Obviously, this only works for the first non-static data member.